# Change div's properties dynamically

Tags: javascript, dom

So I want to create a Menorah and I want to light the candles by clicking the button and let the candle become shorter by, let's say, every second by 5px (for sure this value can be changed). I'm stuck on the animation. I understand that I need to get an access to div's properties, such as height, and also move the candle's light, but I literally have no idea how I can do it.

Here's my code so far:

```js
var lightOn = document.createElement("BUTTON");
lightOn.textContent = "Light Menorah!";
document.body.appendChild(lightOn);
lightOn.onclick = setInterval (candleLight,1000);
function candleLight () {
    document.getElementsByClassName("candles").innerHTML = style.height-10;
    }
```

```css
.candles {
    background-color: blue;
    width: 35px;
    height: 90px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    float: left;
  }
  .mainCandle {
    background-color: blue;
    width: 35px;
    height: 120px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    float: left;
  }
  .light {
    background-color: yellow;
    width: 35px;
    height: 40px;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 10px;
  }
  #theLight {
  }
  #theCandle {
    display:block;
    position: relative;
    padding-top: 40px;
  }
```

```html
<div id = "theLight">
  <div class = "light"></div>
  <div class = "light"></div>
  <div class = "light"></div>
  <div class = "light"></div>
  <div class = "light"></div>
  <div class = "light"></div>
  <div class = "light"></div>
  <div class = "light"></div>
  <div class = "light"></div>
</div>
<div id = "theCandle">
  <div class = "candles"></div>
  <div class = "candles"></div>
  <div class = "candles"></div>
  <div class = "candles"></div>
  <div class = "mainCandle"></div>
  <div class = "candles"></div>
  <div class = "candles"></div>
  <div class = "candles"></div>
  <div class = "candles"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Alice, can you create a JSFiddle? Happy Chanoukkah and Merry Christmas for everyone!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Happy Hanukkah Alice!

You need to go over all of the elements you got from `getElementsByClassName` (that function returns a list of elements, so you can't really use `.innerHTML` on that), and for each of them you need to change the height of the element.

The other problem you got is that you can't use the `style.height` of the element if the height is set using external CSS file. You will need to use the `getComputedStyle` function.

My example below will not fix **all** of your problems, but it will give you a good start (and a general way to solve everything else, I think).

You will still need to fix the positioning problems.

```js
var lightOn = document.createElement("BUTTON");
  lightOn.textContent = "Light Menorah!";
  document.body.appendChild(lightOn);
  lightOn.onclick = function() {
    setInterval (candleLight,1000);
  }
  function candleLight () {
    Array.prototype.forEach.call(
    document.getElementsByClassName("candles"), function(e) {
      height = window.getComputedStyle(e,null).getPropertyValue("height")
      if (parseInt(height)) {
        e.style.height = (parseInt(height)-10) + 'px';
      }
    })
  }
```

```css
.candles {
    background-color: blue;
    width: 35px;
    height: 90px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    float: left;
  }
  .mainCandle {
    background-color: blue;
    width: 35px;
    height: 120px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    float: left;
  }
  .light {
    background-color: yellow;
    width: 35px;
    height: 40px;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 10px;
  }
  #theLight {
  }
  #theCandle {
    display:block;
    position: relative;
    padding-top: 40px;
  }
```

```html
<div id = "theLight">
  <div class = "light"></div>
  <div class = "light"></div>
  <div class = "light"></div>
  <div class = "light"></div>
  <div class = "light"></div>
  <div class = "light"></div>
  <div class = "light"></div>
  <div class = "light"></div>
  <div class = "light"></div>
</div>
<div id = "theCandle">
  <div class = "candles"></div>
  <div class = "candles"></div>
  <div class = "candles"></div>
  <div class = "candles"></div>
  <div class = "mainCandle"></div>
  <div class = "candles"></div>
  <div class = "candles"></div>
  <div class = "candles"></div>
  <div class = "candles"></div>
</div>
```

If something isn't clear yet - please ask :)

Comment: Thank you so much, I will try to fix the positioning. I really got stuck on the logical part, so your explanations are very useful!

Answer (score 2):

Here's the logic you need for shrinking the candles. Your `setInterval` will make it periodic.

```
var candles = undefined;
function candleLight () {
    if (candles === undefined) {
        candles = document.getElementsByClassName("candles")
    }

    for (var candleIndex in candles) {
        candles[candleIndex].style.height = parseInt(candles[candleIndex].style.height.replace("px", "")) + "px";
    }
}
```

Your mistakes were:

- `document.getElementsByClassName` returns an array of elements and the elements on their own have `style` member which has a `height`, also, has an `innerHTML`, but the array itself does not have those
- it was a logical mistake to assign the `height` value to the `innerHTML`
- since your `height` is measured in pixels, it surely ends with `"px"` and is a textual data. As such, you cannot subtract 10 from it. This is remedied in my code suggestion where I remove the `"px"` from the string and parse it to integer calling `parseInt`

Comment: You now... everything here already exists in my answer :) you can also just vote it up

Comment: @Dekel getElementsByClassName returns an array, not a list. My explanation is also more detailed. Nevertheless I have upvoted your answer a long time ago.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @LajosArpad :) Actually - the `getElementsByClassName` function returns an array-like object (not exactly an array, this is why I couldn't use the `forEach` in my example directly on that object. This is why I used the `list` word). Thanks for the vote! You got mine too :)

Comment: Thank you for your explanations, they're also helped me to clarify the picture!